# select from oneToMany with condition

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to select the item from items table when it have an offer if not select it with the original price. For this I have 2 tables items and priceList and this is an example:

```
| itemId | itemName      | 
|--------|---------------|
| 1      | bikex1        |
| 2      | bikex2        |
| 3      | bikex3        |
| 4      | bikex4        | 


| priceIDId | itemID   | itemPrice | priceStatus |
|-----------|----------|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | 1        |100        | offer       |
| 2         | 1        |150        | orignalPrice|
| 4         | 2        |200        | orignalPrice|
```

cause bikex2 have no offer I will get the originalPrice(200) but for the bikex1 I will get the offer price(100)

```
| priceIDId | itemID   | itemPrice | priceStatus |
|-----------|----------|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | 1        |100        | offer       |
| 4         | 2        |200        | orignalPrice|
```

the code I tried is the following :

```
select * from priceList where priceStatus = 'offer' union all select * from priceList where priceStatus = 'orignalPrice' AND  NOT EXISTS (select * from priceList where priceStatus = 'offer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can left join twice:

```
select 
    i.*,
    coalesce(p1.itemPrice, p2.itemPrice) itemPrice,
    coalesce(p1.priceStatus, p2.priceStatus) priceStatus
from items i
left join priceList p1 on p1.itemID = i.itemID and p1.priceStatus = 'offer'
left join priceList p2 on p2.itemID = i.itemID and p1.priceStatus = 'originalPrice'
where coalesce(p1.itemID , p2.itemID) is not null -- at least one of the joins should match
```

Another option is to use use window functions with conditional ordering:

```
select itemID, itemName, itemPrice, priceStatus
from (
    select 
        i.*,
        p.itemPrice,
        p.priceStatus,
        row_number() over(
            partition by p.itemID 
            order by case when p.priceStatus = 'offer' then 0 else 1 
        end) rn
    from items i
    inner join priceList p on p.itemID = i.itemID
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: thank you guys but it have a lot of redundancy or I have to eliminate the bikes that's have original price cause it have already an offer, I tried UNION and DISTINCT but also there are not working
select DSTINCT(itemID) itemPrice from priceList where priceStatus = 'originalPrice'
EXCEPT select * from priceList where priceStatus = 'offer'
UNION 
select DSTINCT(itemID) itemPrice from priceList where priceStatus = 'offer'

Answer (score 0):

The non-standard `DISTINCT ON` clause might be useful here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (itemid)
       priceidid, itemid, itemprice, pricestatus
FROM pricelist
ORDER BY itemid, pricestatus;
```

This relies on the fact that `'offer' < 'orignalPrice'`.

If you want more criteria to select the appropriate row, add them to the `ORDER BY` clause.